# Expected value of a random variable that represents diameter of a circle

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X$ be a random variable that represents the length of the diameter of a circle, we know that $X:\mathcal{U}(5,7)$. Find expected value of circle area.

As far as i know, first, we need density function for this random variable. We know that this variable is uniformly distributed so $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}$. Now, we know that area of a circle is $A=\pi r^2$ where $r$ is radius. As far as i know, formula for expected value is:
$$E(X)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x)dx$$
I have that $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}$. How am i supposed to include formula for area of circle into all of this? Any help appreciated!

Comment: You need to compute $E(\pi X^2)$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two observations:

$\qquad(1)$: $f(x)$ is not $\frac12$, but rather $\frac12 \chi_{[5,7]}$.
In other words, $f$ is $0$ outside $[5,7]$.

$\qquad(2)$: You wish to calculate the expectation of the area, which is $\pi\, (X/2)^2$.
Hence, you wish to calculate

$$\mathbb E\left(\pi {(X/2)}^2\right) = \frac\pi4\,\mathbb E\left( X^2\right).$$

Can you conclude?

Comment: why $\chi ..$ ?

Comment: @GCab Because the density function is $0$ on $\mathbb R\setminus[5,7]$.

Comment: yes, clear, but what do you mean with $\chi$ ? the uniform distr. ?

Comment: Ok so it is actually $\frac{1}{2}$ at segment $[5,7]$ and zero otherwise and when calculating expectation i could actually insert whole function into the integral or just use properties of expectation and just find $E(X)$, multiply it by itself and then by $\frac{\pi}{4}$. Is that right?

Comment: @GCab $\chi_A$ is called the *indicator function* of $A$. By definition we have $\chi_A(x) = 1$ if $x\in A$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: @cdummie The expecation is linear, meaning for two random variables $X, Y$ and some scalar $c$ we have $\mathbb E(cX+Y) = c\,\mathbb E(X) + \mathbb E(Y)$. However, the expectation is in general not multiplicative, meaning $\mathbb E(X^2)$ does not in general equal ${\big(\mathbb E(X)\big)}^2$. This is easy to verify with a coin experiment $C$ that assigns $-1$ to tails and $1$ to heads. Then $\mathbb E(C) = 0$ but $C^2\equiv 1$ so of course $\mathbb E(C^2)  = 1$.

Comment: Now it is clear: you should explicitate in your answer (talking of prob. I was wondering about $\chi$ distrib. ....)

Comment: @GCab Perhaps I should have used $\mathbf 1_{[5,7]}$. This notation is also common and perhaps clearer.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Ok, so i actually have to calculate $E(X^2)$  as $E(g(X))$. Right?

Comment: @cdummie That would be good, yes!

Comment: @ and that used by the OP ,$ \mathcal{U}$, was already enough clear (..)

Comment: @Fimpellizieri thanks a lot, that was very helpful, i understand it much better now!

Comment: Glad to have helped!